# tf.browser.fromPixel(video) causes memory leak

Tags: tensorflow.js

I wanted to get the current frame data from a video using tf.browser.fromPixels(video), but every time this function is called, there is a memory leak.
TensorFlow.js version

> 1.3.1
> Browser version
> Chrome Version 75.0.3770.142
> Here is the code that is causing the memory leak.

```
async function drawScreen () {

    console.log(tf.memory());

    var frame = tf.tidy( () => {

    return  tf.browser.fromPixels (videoElement, 3).expandDims(0).toFloat().div(tf.scalar(255))

    });

    console.log(tf.memory());

    hr_image_0 = tf.tidy( () => {

    return net.execute(frame).squeeze().clipByValue(0,1);

    });

    tf.dispose(frame);

    console.log(tf.memory());

    tf.browser.toPixels(hr_image_0, ccanvas);

    await tf.tidy( () =>  {

     tf.browser.toPixels(hr_image_0, ccanvas);

    });

    console.log(tf.memory());

}
```

I used

> requstAnimationFrame()

to call the drawScreen function.
Running the code on Chrome, the following is printed on the console

> Object { unreliable: false, numBytesInGPU: 210113944, numTensors: 172,numDataBuffers: 172, numBytes: 211660580 }
>
> CH6EX8.html:129:11 Object {unreliable: false, numBytesInGPU:
> 210344344, numTensors: 173,nnumDataBuffers: 173, numBytes: 211833380 }
>
> CH6EX8.html:135:11 Object {unreliable: false, numBytesInGPU:
> 212187544, numTensors: 173, numDataBuffers: 173, numBytes: 213215780 }
>
> CH6EX8.html:141:11 Object {  unreliable: false, numBytesInGPU:
> 213745048, numTensors: 173, numDataBuffers: 173, numBytes: 213215780 }

Is there any way to remove the leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the doc:

> Executes the provided function fn and after it is executed, cleans up all intermediate tensors allocated by fn except those returned by fn

`tf.tidy` does remove intermediate tensor. But in this case there is not any intermediate tensor to remove. And the buffer will keep increasing as you keep calling the drawscreen method which will always return `tf.browser.fromPixels (videoElement, 3).expandDims(0).toFloat().div(tf.scalar(255))` thus keeping the buffer allocated to the creation of the tensor in memory.

To clean the unused tensor, the method calling `drawScreen` should be enclosed in `tf.tidy` to dispose the tensor used when creating the tensor from image.

Since `drawScreen` is called by requestAnimation, `tf.tidy` can be a toplevel function inside it.

```
async function drawScreen () {
  tf.tidy(() => {
   // do all operations here
  })
}
```

The other option would be to use `tf.dispose` to dispose `frame` and `hr_image_0` after the image has been drawn to the screen

```
await tf.browser.toPixels(hr_image_0, ccanvas);
tf.dispose(hr_image_0)
```

Comment: I already tried that, but it is not working. If I do like that, it won't even draw the current frame. Instead, it prints "Tensor is disposed".

Comment: I think that you would need to await the tf.browser.fromPixels before disposing the tensors

Comment: I actually tried both ways, but still not working. My guess is that `tf.browser.toPixels` is leaking memory internally.

Comment: You mean you disposed the tensor after await ? Can you tell what is the memory used before and after the tensor disposal ?