# Memory leak when using tf.browser.toPixels()

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

The following line is causing a memory leak .

`await tf.browser.toPixels(val, temp);`

`val` is an array of dimensions `img_size * img_size` and `temp` is a canvas  . One tensor is not being disposed . Since it is an asynchronous call it cannot be put inside a `tf.tidy()` . Also according to official documentation `tf.browser.toPixels()` should return  a promise .So how can we dispose the tensor which is being formed ? (Size of tensor = img_size * img_size *4 )

Relevant Code :

```js
let val ;     //val is an array not a tensor
        tf.tidy(()=>{
        let values = model.predict(batched).dataSync(); //batched is a tensor
        values = Array.from(values);
        //scale values
        values = values.map(x => x * 255)
        val = new Array();
        while (values.length > 0) val.push(values.splice(0, image_size));
        });
        await tf.browser.toPixels(val, temp); //this line causes leak,commenting it fixes it
        finalRes.getContext('2d').drawImage(temp, dx, dy);
```

Comment: Can you please show a relevant part of your code ? It will be easier to help

Answer (score 1):

This was an internal bug in `tfjs` . It has been fixed now [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/264#event-3227792778)

Answer (score 0):

the tensor needs to be disposed explicitly after using `tf.browser.toPixels`

```
tf.dispose(val)
```

More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59143276/tf-browser-frompixelvideo-causes-memory-leak/59144150#59144150)

Comment: ```val ```  is an array . It is not a tensor.  So ```tf.dispose(val ) ``` gives an error .

Comment: Okay `val` is an array and it is causing memory leak ? Maybe you can do a working sinppet demonstration your issue. It will be easier to dig into it